# WP Sorting custom posts alphabetically by Title

Tags: php, wordpress

Newbie here...

I have a custom post type of 'equipe' (team in portuguese). I am trying to sort these alphabetically by post title then display the_title so we have a alphabetical list of names.

I've done a search on here and tried a few fixes but Im struggling to get anything other that the standard order.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```html
      <?php
       $args = array('orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'equipe',  'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish' );
       $q = new WP_Query($args);
       while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
      ?>

         <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

      <?php
       endwhile;
       wp_reset_query();
      ?>
```

Comment: what is equipe is this a category

Comment: its a custom post type setup via the CPT UI plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'equipe', 'posts_per_page'=>5, 'orderby'=>'post_title','order'=>'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, But unfortunately that doesn't seem to be outputting alpabetically:

Comment: A-Z
Gabriel Di Blasi
Paulo Parente Marques Mendes
Marcelo Oliveira de Souza
Renata Hohl
Elyssa Michelle LeFevre Chayo
Bárbara Leitão
Ludmila Kawakami Ávila
Renato Venturini Matrangolo
Isabella Ulrike Paul
Fernanda Mósca Tavares Dias
Érica Souza

Comment: replace title with post_title in query

Comment: Same output sadly

Comment: Actually “title” and “post_title” are both accepted. :) Do you have a clue about what order the list follows? (E.g. is it in publishing date order, ID order, or just random?)

Comment: last try this title+0.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Hey guys, unfortunately neither 'title+0' or title+0 works. I believe the order is by date. Nothing I try seems to change this order? :-(

Comment: it works perfectly on me when i'm using in follower list

Comment: I've just tested the loop with another post type 'eventos' and this looks to work here. Just not with the 'equipe' post type???? This post type only seems to list in the same order???

Comment: Im wondering if this is because the 'eventos' post type has no categories but 'equipe' post type has a number of categories??

Comment: Even when I add 'category_name'=> 'Patentes' into the array to restrict the amount of results. It still wont change the order...

Comment: OK, i've seen that it's ordering by Menu Order

Comment: Anyway to set menu_order = 0 for this particular page??

Comment: maybe character encoding problem

Comment: any fix for that?

Comment: i don't know sorry

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

Ok the reason it was enforcing menu_order was because of a setting (F*ing checkbox) within the plugin Post Types Order.

I needed to un-check AUTO SORT
and check Use query ASC / DESC parameter

This then allowed me to adjust the array as follow (and discussed above):
$args = array('orderby' => 'title', 'order'=>'ASC', 'post_type' => 'equipe')

However I did need to add 'order'=>'ASC' into the other pages that sorted by the original query of menu_order.